# Cron job using codeigniter on an ubuntu server

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm having trouble setting up a cron job.

I have a cron job created at a url like so:

myurl.com/cron

When that link is accessed, it is run.

How do I set it so that it runs automatically, every 10 minutes?

I can't figure out how to create a cron job.  I know that that's what I need to do, but I can't figure out how to do it for a ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login via SSH and in the shell, type the following:

```
crontab -e
```

Then, place the following line:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/command
```

Save the file and that command will be called every 10 minutes.

Comment: After i enter crontab -e I am given an infinite amount of ~ symbols

Comment: Yes, then simply type the command I mentioned and when you are done, press ESC and type :wq and then press ENTER to save.

Comment: The cron is not in a file like .php.  It is mysite.com/cron    How can I set the path/to/command to /cron?

Comment: You would do */10 * * * * php /path/to/wwwroot/cron/index.php

Comment: Since you are using CodeIgniter, you can also try this: `*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q http://www.yoursite.com/cron`